# Calling Twitter API in Xcode iPhone Application

Tags: ios, xcode, twitter

Is there any wrapper available for Twitter in X-Code? if not then do I have to call original Twitter API in my iPhone's application?

Answer (score 1):

Why not give http://mattgemmell.com/2008/02/22/mgtwitterengine-twitter-from-cocoa a go, it works with the iPhone and has been recommended by quite a few people.

Answer (score 0):

You can try [MGTwitterEngine](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/02/22/mgtwitterengine-twitter-from-cocoa).

I am just starting to look at it myself.